# Can't print - 'Backend' failed

Tags: printing, bonjour

Using a MBP running Catalina 10.15.6 I am unable to print to a networked Xerox printer.  It discovers it just fine with Bonjour, connects, but when I print anything, it instantly pauses the printer, and in the printer job list dialog, it fails saying `Ready to Print - 'Backend' failed, 2 pages`.

I've tried re-adding the printer, `Reset the printing system` with the right-click in the printer list, rebooting the machine.  I have an old iMac also running 10.15.6 which can print to it, so I know the printer works.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Wondering here, what if you add it *manually* with an IP address rather than Bonjour discovery

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround.  (Of course after struggling with this for weeks, I figure it out just after posting the question.)

When adding the printer, the dialog asks for "Name", "Location" and "Use".  "Use" defaults to "Secure AirPrint", but changing this to "AirPrint" fixes the problem.  It's a Xerox printer, FWIW.